# How to match the white space between two strings in vim?

Tags: vim

```
4250682 orderNumber: 60360981400                         orderID：4250682
```

There could be white spaces or tab between "60360981400" and "orderID". How to match those spaces and replace it with only one space?

```
orderNumber：\d\+.*orderID
```

This can match the pattern. But how to replace the '.*' with one space?

Comment: Why did you close it???

Comment: How about `:s/\v\s+/ /g`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suitable for https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match only a part of the regex expression, you can use `\zs` (start of match) and `\ze` (end of match) expressions: the matching part before `\zs` and after `\ze` will be discarded, thus the inner match will be replaced:

```
s/orderNumber: \d\+\zs.*\zeorderID/ /
```

For additional details, see [`:help \zs`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Czs).

Answer (score 0):

In order to replace all instances of consecutive whitespaces with one space, you can use the whitespace metacharacter `\s`, as in `:s/\s\+/ /g`.

Or look into grouping and backreferences:  `:s/\(orderNumber: \d\+\).*\(orderID\)/\1 \2/`

http://vimregex.com/ will explain all of the above and a lot more.